# Breeze, OData, and no EF

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze

I'm learning breeze nowadays and I want to ask about using breeze without EF.

The BreezeController exposes IQueryable for all entities. When a breeze request comes,OData format is used for the query, this means with EF, the query will be prepared and only filtered data will be brought forward.

In the case of non-EF, like a 3rd party API to retrieve data from SQ: Server, will I have to expose all data on the controller and have data returned filtered by the query received by Breeze?

Appreciate your help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can expose as large or as small of a surface as you want on the server.  Filtering can occur either on the client via a Breeze where clause or on the server when you create an IQueryable that exposes only a subset collection of some entity type.  Moreover you can also use the Breeze EntityQuery.withParameters method if you want to expose an api that is either not queryable or queryable thru semantics other than IQueryable.